# Empty the Cart and Add the Product Via Link

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, ce-1.9.0.1, cart-rule

Situation:
I have this single product cart as rules on my cart page. What I did was I detect the other product being added by the user and display it on the top of the cart. See this photo:
[image: Second Item Added Notification]

I want that when you click the continue button the Product on the Cart will be Empty and Replace by the Product Listed on the Notification.
Can a link like /checkout/cart//?id= do that?
If not what would be the possible thing to do?
**Note: This is on the Shopping Cart Page.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to go a little fancy for this. Extend the cart controller in your module and add some function, lets say it singlecartAction. It will look something like this :

```
public function singlecartAction() {
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();

    try {
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

        if (!$product) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }

        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        if (!empty($related)) {
            $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }

        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
            $this->_goBack();
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } else {
            $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
            }
        }

        $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } else {
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

Basically, I just combined functions of emptying the cart and adding product to the cart. You can wrap some try-catch around it and remove some extra code if you want.

Comment: can I call the function via link? if yes what would be the link?

Comment: I guess it will be /checkout/cart/singlecart... am I right @Prateek ?

Comment: I did add the code and what I get was an empty cart only.

Comment: I did edit it @Prateek and the code works great except for the Success Message is not on the top most.

Comment: It's based on default cart controller. Success message is being added to the session which will be displayed along with any other session messages on next page load. Can you elaborate a little what exactly is the issue you are facing with this ?

Comment: I did solve it by putting the message on the session.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy
**Use below code in Product View Page just after $_product is defined.**

**To Empty the Cart**

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
```

**Add the Product Via Link**

```
$_formKey= Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();     
$_productAddToCartLink= Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add',array('product'=>$_product->getId(), 'form_key'=> $_formKey));

<a href="<?php echo $_productAddToCartLink?>">Product Add To Cart Link</a>
```

Comment: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Copy this file to your theme & put after $_product is defined. The link would be display on each product view page.

Comment: How to trigger the cart to be empty first before adding the product?

Comment: This must happen on the Shopping Cart Page not on the Product Page.

Comment: When a new product will be added to cart. Cart will be empty automatically.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.